# How to check if browser cached JS library or not?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have custom build JS library (which is `swiper.js`). Can I check if the browser has its CDN version in the cache before downloading it? Normally it's 130KB but my desired version (contain few fewer functions) is just 70KB so I don't want to add those extra KBs to get it from CDN if the user has not already cached it. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Just for clarity, you decide via your markup(html) as to what file the browser should download.  So in the case of checking if there's a previous version of a file that you want to refresh, you can simply add a parameter at the end of the file to make the URL unique such that the browser doesn't use one that's prevously downloaded.

Here's an example link:

```
swipser.js?version=<version or date saved>
```

So each time a browser see this, it will not download unless the parameter has changed, or perhaps the user has cleared their cache

Comment: Sorry you take it wrong. Hashing is needed when you're using local js file. I asked something different like I want to check if someone has already cached it from CDN while visiting any website before. In that case I don't want user download it but if this is not in cache he'll grab smaller version from my web instead of full which is available to him on official CDN. In short I don't want to use CDN unless not cached before.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding my reference to hash, so I've modified my comment to remove confusion.  The parameter can be any random string.